# php & javascript open window function

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

I try to use window.open but so far it doesn't work

```
<script type="text" language="javascript">    
function win1(j){
    window.open("ctry.php?j=" + j,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
</script>

<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){  
?>
<a href="javascript:win1('<?php echo $j;?>')" 
  onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;"><b>Open Window</b></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

When I click on the link nothing happened and on the console i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: win1 is not defined
```

Do you know what can i do?
Thanks

Comment: Please check this page its may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103770/open-a-php-page-from-javascript-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function win1(j){
    window.open("ctry.php?j=" + j,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
</script>

<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){  
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;" onClick="win1('<?php echo $j;?>')"><b>Open Window</b></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:win1('<?php echo $j;?>')"  onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;"><b>Open Window</b></a>` This will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<script type="text" language="javascript">` with `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting this code inside body tag or inside head? Cause you cannot put html in head

Comment: It is known from the question that the link is displayed in the output.

Answer (score -1):

Your JS action is to be on onclick action, not on href, try this elow code

```
<a href="#" onclick="win1('<?php echo $j;?>')"
  onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;"><b>Open Window</b></a>
```