# PHP code inside script tag for redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of users besides that are the delete button. Where in when you click the delete button a confirm() script will appear. I used this code but the one being deleted is always the last id.

```
button onclick="myFunction()">Delete</button></td>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?") == true) {
            window.location.href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $r->id); ?>";
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please go through this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103770/open-a-php-page-from-javascript-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $r->id; ?>)">Delete</button></td>
            <script>
                function myFunction(id) {
                    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?") == true) {
                        window.location.href = "delete.php?id="+id;
                        } else {
                                //
                        }
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: `"delete.php?id=" + id`

Comment: I can't up vote your answer, but thank you so much madforstrength and u_mulder

Comment: @Hiei do you understand the problem with what you were doing?

Comment: @RobertGrant No. I actually have no knowledge in Javascript, but I will learn it when I get good in PHP.